# Parallel caused this "error mustOpen: Can't open - to read: No such file or directory"

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gnu-parallel

I tried to use parallel command in the following way:

```
cat asm.contig.fasta | parallel -k --block 1k --recstart '>' --pipe 'blat -t=dnax -q=prot - ../swissprot.fasta out{#}.psl -noHead'
```

but unfortunately I got this error:

```
mustOpen: Can't open - to read: No such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not from GNU Parallel, so it is from `blat`. I have not used `blat` for years, so I am not 100% sure of the following.

My guess is that you cannot use use `-` to denote STDIN for the database in `blat`.

There are several ways of tickling `blat`. Use `/dev/stdin` which will give the standard input as a fifo on many systems:

```
cat asm.contig.fasta | parallel -k --block 1k --recstart '>' --pipe 'blat -t=dnax -q=prot /dev/stdin ../swissprot.fasta out{#}.psl -noHead'
```

Use `--fifo` which will make a fifo/named pipe which will give the standard in put as a fifo on all supported systems. After the command is completed the fifo will be removed:

```
cat asm.contig.fasta | parallel --fifo -k --block 1k --recstart '>' --pipe 'blat -t=dnax -q=prot {} ../swissprot.fasta out{#}.psl -noHead'
```

Use `--cat` which will make a regular file containing the 1k block of data. After the command is completed the file will be removed.

```
cat asm.contig.fasta | parallel --cat -k --block 1k --recstart '>' --pipe 'blat -t=dnax -q=prot {} ../swissprot.fasta out{#}.psl -noHead'
```

`--cat` is generally the slowest (for `--block 1k` expect an additional 1 ms per job), but almost guaranteed to work.

Let us know which one worked.

Comment: The first command complained about `Expecting '>' line 1 of /dev/stdin`. The second command produced only 100 commands. The third command works fine. Thank you